# Installation Lizmap web client - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, lizmap

How to give the access rights to access "localhost / lm" since I have the error 403 "forbidden you do not have ....."

Can the problem come from there??[image: droit pour apache]

Comment: Please remember to always provide error messages as text in the body of the question. Images are okay for supplemental vale, but are neither legible on all devices nor searchable by other users.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably an error in your server configuration.

We need more information about your lizmap installation if you want some helps :
* Ubuntu version
* Server used : apache or nginx
* Lizmap web client version
* QGIS Server version

If you use apache, your vhost configuration is not well done. I invite you to check **Apache Error 403**  to fix your issue.

Please use the lizmap mailing list  https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/lizmap or the github repository .